# Error while updating

Tags: 8, updating

Updated Drupal from 8.7.8 to 8.8.0 with:

```
composer update --with-dependencies
```

That part went well, but when I run:

```
drush updb
```

I get following error:

```
In ProcessBase.php line 188:

  Unable to decode output into JSON: Syntax error                                                                             

  Error: Call to a member function getConfigDependencyKey() on null in Drupal\taxonomy\Plugin\views\filter\TaxonomyIndexTid-  
  >calculateDependencies() (line 394 of /var/www/html/drupal/web/core/modules/taxonomy/src/Plugin/views/filter/TaxonomyIndex  
  Tid.php).
```

Checked the code a bit and it goes like:

```
  public function calculateDependencies() {
    $dependencies = parent::calculateDependencies();

    $vocabulary = $this->vocabularyStorage->load($this->options['vid']);
    $dependencies[$vocabulary->getConfigDependencyKey()][] = $vocabulary->getConfigDependencyName(); // <-- line 394

...
```

And `$this->options['vid']` is empty and `$vocabulary` var becomes null.

Any idea what's wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

just to make you aware in case you're using the Pathauto module and you didn't notice:

> Changes to path aliases and a critical note for sites using the Pathauto contributed module
>   If you have the contributed Pathauto module enabled, you must update to the latest version of Pathauto **before** you update to Drupal 8.8.0. Failure to update Pathauto before updating core could result in data loss. Drupal 8.8.0 declares a conflict with Pathauto 8.x-1.5 or lower for this reason.

https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/releases/8.8.0

Can't say anything about your specific error though.

Comment: I didn't install it on my own. I don't have it on "Extend" admin page nor in composer.json file. But inside composer.lock I do have it under "conflict" section. But I guess that's ok?

Comment: The *conflict* section just says there is a conflict between two packages. Drupal 8.8 reports it conflicts with Pathauto module versions prior to 8.x-1.6.